# web driver update error response status code is not 200

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, chrome-web-driver

iam trying to install webdriver-manager 
by issuing the command

```
webdriver-manager update
```

and iam getting the following output

```
webdriver-manager: using global installed version 12.0.6
(node:6312) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejec
tion id: 1): Error: response status code is not 200
(node:6312) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are depre
cated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
 Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:6312) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejec
tion id: 2): Error: response status code is not 200
[16:32:42] I/update - geckodriver: file exists C:\Users\osheikh\AppData\Roaming\
npm\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\geckodriver-v0.19.1.zip
[16:32:42] I/update - geckodriver: unzipping geckodriver-v0.19.1.zip
[16:32:42] I/update - geckodriver: geckodriver-v0.19.1.exe up to date
```

what does the error response status code is not 200 refers to

my webdriver-manager status output is

```
C:\Windows\system32>webdriver-manager status
webdriver-manager: using global installed version 12.0.6
[15:58:44] I/status - geckodriver version available: v0.19.1
[15:58:44] I/status - selenium standalone is not present
[15:58:44] I/status - chromedriver is not present
[15:58:44] I/status - IEDriverServer is not present
[15:58:44] I/status - android-sdk is not present
[15:58:44] I/status - appium is not present
```

my java version and protractor version are as following

```
C:\Windows\system32>java -version
java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)

C:\Windows\system32>protractor --version
Version 5.3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try webdriver-manager update --ignore_ssl or --proxy

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem and I spend hours to find out how to solve the problem. In the generated error before redlines of error I find this message:

I/config_source - curl -oE:\sample projects\sample\node_modules \protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chrome-response.xml https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/

I ran this command on console (In my case I used the Proxy server because googleleapis is blocked in my country)

```
curl -o "E:\sample projects\sample\node_modules \protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chrome-response.xml" https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/`enter code here`
```

After running this command separately the original `ng e2e` command executed successfully!
I think **space** in the path of my application (in my  sample path: **.../sample projects/..**) had caused the bug!